# Stop method and loop in callback

Tags: c#, loops, methods, callback, break

**Question 1.** I wonder if it's possible to stop the loop in the inside operation's callback?
**Question 2.** Can I stop `SomeMethod()` in the callback?

E.g. I have a code like:

```
foreach(...)
{
   myObject.SomeMethod(s =>
      {
         // something break-like here to stop foreach/method?
      });
}
```

**[edit]**

Here's the example of the code I use - it doesn't work as I want.

```
bool test = false;
foreach (var drive in drives)
{
    foundFolders.AddRange(
        DirectoryWrapper.GetDirectories(drive, regex, true, s =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => SetWarningStatus(WarningTypes.Warning,
                                                                    "Looking for backups: " + Environment.NewLine + s.Trim())), DispatcherPriority.Background);
                test = true;
                return;
            }));
    if (test)
        break;
}
```

Even `Resharper` says that `return` is redundant here...

**Solution**
After @Tigran's suggestion I noticed that always what I should do is to change my `GetDirectories` definition.

From:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string root, string searchRegex, bool skipSystemDirs = false, Action<string> callback = null) {}
```

To:

```
public delegate bool MyCallback(string s);
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string root, string searchRegex, bool skipSystemDirs = false, MyCallback callback = null)
```

Then I can return a flag inside a callback function and serve it inside `GetDirectories()`.

Btw. what's interesting, when we have our `"GetDirectories"` as a binary, then we probably can't stop it in delegate... We have to wait until its execution finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

You can if use the variable which will be captured by lambda. Like:

```
foreach(...)
{
   var stopIteration  =false;    
   myObject.SomeMethod(s =>
      {
          ...

          stopIteration   = true; //due the some condition
      });

   if(stopIteration)break;
}
```

Question 2:

Just use `return`

```
myObject.SomeMethod(s =>
{
     //something gone wrong, or need exit; 
      return;
});
```

Comment: Yes, but it's a problem with this case. I have to wait for my `SomeMethod` to finish to check the condition. But what if I wanted break the loop immediately?

Comment: @Nickon: use both techniques: so set *stopIteration=true; return;*

Comment: Then return from lambda immediately.

Comment: @Tigran this is some idea:) if this return works, the case is already solved:) thx

Comment: I'm afraid that `return` stops only callback action, not `SomeMethod`:/

Comment: @Nickon: it depends on *where* do you put return. If you put it inside SomeMethod(=> , it will break its execution. If the boolean set to TRUE, the foreach will catch it and break iteration too.

Comment: I did exactly as u described in your code. It doesn't work:S `return` stops only delegate `Action`

Comment: @Nickon: please show how your code is structured. not all code, but only structure of it.

Comment: @Nickon: resharoer right on this. What do you want to achieve here ? *When* you have to leave that method ?

Comment: I want to stop `SomeMethod` in the callback

Comment: @Nickon: so you want to stop GetDirectories if something went wrong in SetWarningStatus ??

Comment: @Nickon: that means that SetWarningStatus has to return some result about *success* or *failure* of operation executed. Based on that value GetDirectories decides if it need to return (but before set boolean to TRUE, so the for iteration will stop too)

Comment: @Nickon: yes, in some way you need to psuh up to the calling stack the resulting value of your execution, so the chain of callers can catch it and behave appropriately.